# BackgroundPanel my background image overwrites all my components

Tags: java

```
private JPanel contentPane;
// instance variables
private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 350;

private static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 150;
private static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN = 150;

private static final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 90;
private static final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 30;
private JButton readFile;
private JButton exit;
private JButton stats;
private JButton blank;

private JPanel action;
```

---

```
public Potion() {
        // desativando logs
        LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
        logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        //-----------------------------------------------
        //background color
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
             File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Gabriel\\Desktop\\mu.png");
             img = ImageIO.read(f);
             System.out.println("File " + f.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot read file: " + e);
        }

        BackgroundPanel background = new BackgroundPanel(img, BackgroundPanel.TILED, 0.50f, 0.5f);
        //fim
        //-----------------------------------------------
        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout());

        setContentPane(background);

        //Set the frame properties
        setSize         (FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setResizable    (false);
        setTitle        ("CSCE155A Course Offerings Viewer");
        setLocation     (FRAME_X_ORIGIN, FRAME_Y_ORIGIN);

        //Create and Place the Buttons on the frame
        readFile = new JButton("Read File");
        readFile.setBounds(4, 285, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);


        exit = new JButton("Exit");
        exit.setBounds(100, 285, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);


        stats = new JButton("Stats");
        stats.setBounds(195, 285, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);


        blank = new JButton("Clear");
        blank.setBounds(290, 285, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);

        action = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        action.setBackground(Color.blue);
        action.add(readFile); 
        action.add(exit);
        action.add(stats);
        action.add(blank);
        contentPane.add(action);

    }
```

I'm using the class: BackgroundPanel to add an image to my frame

// background color

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
     File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Gabriel\\Desktop\\mu.png");
     img = ImageIO.read(f);
     System.out.println("File " + f.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Cannot read file: " + e);
}

BackgroundPanel background = new BackgroundPanel(img, BackgroundPanel.TILED, 0.50f, 0.5f);
```

but when I'm going to do:

setContentPane (background);

The image overwrites all my other panel:

> action = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
>       action.setBackground(Color.blue);
>       action.add(readFile); 
>       action.add(exit);
>       contentPane.add(action);

My background is overwriting my action panel and all my buttons and I'm not able to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what you're doing:

Here you create your BackgroundPanel object:

```
BackgroundPanel background = new BackgroundPanel(img, BackgroundPanel.TILED, 0.50f, 0.5f);
```

And here you extract the JFrame's ***current*** contentPane, the contentPane ***before*** the swap

```
JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout());
```

Now you swap contentPanes such that the background JPanel is contentPane ***but the contentPane variable still refers to the old contentPane***, the one ***no longer being displayed***

```
setContentPane(background);

//.... other code
```

Now you create a new JPanel, add things to it:

```
action = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
action.setBackground(Color.blue);
action.add(readFile); 
action.add(exit);
action.add(stats);
action.add(blank);
```

and then add it to the contentPane variable ***which is no longer displayed***

```
contentPane.add(action);
```

So of course, your components will not be displayed.  Instead add the action JPanel to your background JPanel

Comment: Thanks, I do not understand very well.
how would I do that?

Comment: @CarlosMontana: `background.add(action);`